# Variable not initialized

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, initialization

I'm writing a program for the "University Book Store" for a class. And I feel like everything should be working, but for publishingPrice and markup, I'm getting a "Variable not initialized" error. Yet I gave them both values. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Netbeans.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProgrammingProject {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Set my variables for the program
        double publisherPrice;
        double newBook;
        double usedBook;
        double usedBookDiscount;
        double rentalBook;
        double rentalBookDiscount;
        double markup;
        int booksOrdered;

        String bookName;

        System.out.println("Enter the Book Title: ");
        bookName = keyboard.next();


        System.out.println("Enter the Amount of Books Ordered: ");
        booksOrdered = keyboard.nextInt();

                //Set the conditions for markup
        if (booksOrdered < 20) {
            markup = .40;
                    }
        if (booksOrdered >= 20 && booksOrdered < 50){
            markup = .35;
                    }
        if (booksOrdered >= 50 && booksOrdered < 100){
            markup = .30;
                    }
        if (booksOrdered >=100){
            markup = .25;
        }



        //Set calculations for program to use

        usedBookDiscount = .75;
        rentalBookDiscount = .40;
        newBook = (publisherPrice + markup);
        usedBook = ((newBook * usedBookDiscount) - usedBookDiscount);
        rentalBook = ((newBook * rentalBookDiscount - rentalBookDiscount));

        System.out.println(bookName + publisherPrice + newBook + usedBook + rentalBook);



                }
}
```

Comment: the error says it all

Comment: That error message is self-explanatory. I don't see any code to give `publishingPrice` and `markup` any value at all.

Comment: I didn't realize that I hadn't asked for input for publishingPrice yet, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You only assign a value to `markup` within `if` statements. The compiler doesn't keep track of what's feasible, and whether you've covered all cases... so the variable still isn't definitely assigned as far as the compiler is concerned.

The simplest fix is to use `else` instead:

```
if (booksOrdered < 20) {
    markup = .40;
} else if (booksOrdered < 50) {
    markup = .35;
} else if (booksOrdered < 100) {
    markup = .30;     
} else {
    markup = .25;
}
```

Because the final `else` is unconditional, the compiler will spot that every path through this code assigns a value to `markup`.

That's enough for `markup` - but you haven't specified anything that will assign a value to `publisherPrice`. Was that meant to be set via more user input? Note that it would be easier to spot all of this if you assign values to your variables at the point of declaration, rather than declaring everything at the start of the method and then assigning values.

For example, instead of this:

```
String bookName;

System.out.println("Enter the Book Title: ");
bookName = keyboard.next();
```

... you can have:

```
System.out.println("Enter the Book Title: ");
String bookName = keyboard.next();
```

As another side note, you shouldn't generally use `double` for financial amounts - consider using `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: not related but consider that with the `else if` `booksOrdered>=x` is not necesary anymore

Comment: Thank you, this helped significantly. I am a freshman in college and this is my first programming class. Is there any reason that it messes up if I use a book title with more than one word or a number (Ex Calculus 101 as book title skips the amount of books ordered step) (Ex Harry potter causes an error)?

Comment: @JarodWood: Read the documentation for `Scanner.next()` :) If you want it to accept a line at a time instead, I'd probably just use a `BufferedReader` around `System.in`, and call `readLine` to read the next line of text.

Answer (score 1):

All of your variables must be initialized with values before you can perform arithmetic on them.